# Plural form of “stuff”

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it correct to use the plural form of *stuff* as in this sentence:

> I have packed all my stuffs.

Should the singular be used or there is no difference in meaning?

Answer (score 7):

[Stuff](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stuff) is usually uncountable, so you do not use a plural.

It is used in the same way as, say, water:

> I drank all my water.
>   I packed all my stuff.

*Usually*, because in some (rare) cases you might want to use a plural.

I bought 6 kinds of bottled water. I have tasted all 6 waters, but they all taste the same to me.
I guess you could do something similar with stuff.

Comment: for water, yes a plural sometimes makes sense. But for stuff?

Comment: I was just quoting wiktionary on the `usually`. I have to admit I couldn't easily come up with a reasonable example :) Maybe you can have different foodstuffs? (Yes, my spell checker accepts it :P )

Comment: foodstuffs yes. But that's not stuffs, but rather a commonly accepted word for "food items".

Comment: Just going out on a limb here. Ask Wiktionary for exceptions of the "usually", I don't have any :P See Leon Conrad's answer :)

Comment: In saying 'I have tasted all 6 waters' you're actually saying 'I have tasted all 6 Brands/Glasses/Types of water'. So it remains with water not having a plural - being an uncountable noun.

Comment: Well, I could have gone with "her waters have broken", but I'd be at a loss to explain the plural form there :P Or maybe [the Blue waters of the North](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DNkKj_GS9R-o&ei=mP_4UqK9BaTSywPGpoDYCA&usg=AFQjCNHZrbHVozHJopzSR0wCcx5D3rjQHA&sig2=W_nv1bIjOiUU9ghstGJh-A&bvm=bv.60983673,d.bGQ)

Comment: My 20 years old Oxford Advance Learner's dictionary says STUFF is both a countable and uncountable noun. Is the dictionary wrong or the word has been changed to just a uncountable noun only?

Comment: @JohnLee: no, I simply had trouble finding an example, but as mentioned by Leon Conrad in his answer, your OALD doesn't seem to be too outdated :)

Comment: Suppose several friends come to visit me and each of them being me some stuff. Can I say "thank you guys for the stuffs"?

Comment: Nopes. In that case stuff is uncountable. Think of them bringing food.

Answer (score 1):

There are several meanings of the word. The most general is almost as wide as 'thingamijig' or 'thing'. In this sense, the general term is used in singular form.

However, if referring to a particular kind of 'thing', such as cloth, see def. no. 4 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Stuff?s=t), it would be quite feasible to use the plural form.

It is in this sense that the word has been used as a suffix in words like, for example, foodstuff(s) which is frequently found in both single and plural forms.